# Telegram API. Отправка сообщения с сервера

Tags: php, telegram, whatsapp

Доброго дня! Подскажите плиз как с сервера передать сообщение с необходимой информацией "самому себе", реально ли это вообще или только в Боты?

На сколько я понял по WhatsApp API сейчас нет такой функции, быть может есть в Телеграмме?

Comment: для нативного апи придётся поддержать их протокол, mt proto, или просто использовать готовые либы типа https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить запрос вида
`https://api.telegram.org/{токен_бота}/sendMessage?chat_id={твой_id}&text={текст}`

Comment: Да, спасибо, про такой вариант читал.. Но на сколько я понимаю передается сообщение в Бота, а можно ли передать сообщение пользователю по номеру телефона?

Comment: @K.Mitnick нет, это же не Viber

Comment: А по поводу WhatsApp не в курсе? Кажется API закрыли они... сообщения на телефон на сколько знаю передать тоже нельзя... ChatAPI не катит уже видимо